# Configuring Lambda to retrieve all the messages in DLQ

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda configured to a DLQ that may have a few messages in a day. I'm using java for lambda function. My Handler class and method looks something like this:

```
public class LambdaMethodHandler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context){

        context.getLogger().log("Started processing messages in DLQ");
        List<String> failedMessages = new ArrayList<>();

        event.getRecords().stream().forEach(message -> {
            context.getLogger().log("Message body: "+message.getBody()+", Message sent on: "+message.getMessageAttributes().get("timestamp")+", Message ID: "+message.getMessageId());
            failedMessages.add(message.getBody());
        });
```

The idea was to trigger this lambda once a day using EventBridge and if there are multiple messages in the DLQ, it should iterate through them and save it in a file. So I assumed that in `SQSEvent` the records field is a List so ideally if there are multiple messages in the DLQ then these messages will be passed as `List<SQSMessage> records` in the SQSEvent. But as I was testing(for now by manually adding messages to the DLQ before configuring the lambda), if there were multiple messages, it would just trigger the lambda multiple time.

Not sure if I've understood the concept incorrectly or is there something wrong with my implementation.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, you're scheduling the Lambda function to run so the event source will never be SQS. It will be a scheduled event (example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-run-lambda-schedule.html)). Your Lambda function would have to programmatically request messages from the SQS queue.

Comment: Is there a way where SQS can be the event source but the lambda executes only once per day? So the messages are in queue till the lambda runs and the lambda will process all the messages in the DLQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda is written as though it is subscribed to your SQS queue, which you don't want, since EventBridge will be triggering your lambda directly. You would only use SQSEvent in your handler if the lambda were being triggered by an SQS subscription rather than an EventBridge rule.

To make it run on a schedule:

1. Unsubscribe your lambda from the SQS queue.
2. Make your lambda the target of your EventBridge rule.
3. Update the handler to receive a generic request from EventBridge, i.e.:

   ```java
   public class LambdaMethodHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, String> {

       @Override
       public String handleRequest(Map<String, Object> event, Context context) {
   ```

   This is required because [there's currently no EventBridgeEvent until events v4](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/issues/109#issuecomment-1104429751).
4. Receive/delete your messages manually. Lambdas that receive SQS messages on a schedule have to manually read messages from the SQS queue and delete them when they're done. In java you would use a [ReceiveMessageRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-sqs-messages.html#sqs-messages-receive) and then delete it afterward with a [DeleteMessageRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-sqs-messages.html#sqs-messages-delete).

Comment: The ReceiveMessageRequest does not retrieve all the messages in the queue. [Raised a question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73689410/sqs-receivemessagerequest-not-receiving-all-the-messages-in-the-queue-messages)