# SQS ReceiveMessageRequest not receiving all the messages in the queue (messages are under 10)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to retrieve messages from a queue. I understand that `RecieveMessageRequest` has a threshold of 10 messages but when I tried I was able to receive only 2 out 3 messages in the queue. I read many threads which said adding `setMaxNumberOfMessages(10)` and increasing `WaitTimeSeconds` will fix it(Before adding this I received only one message out of 3) but it wasn't helpful.

FYI: I'm using a standard queue and all the messages were definitely there in the queue at the time of receive message request so it shouldn't have been a polling issue.

My implementation:

```
List<Message> messages;

ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest().withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .withWaitTimeSeconds(10)
                    .withMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
           
messages = sqsConfig.getSQSClient().receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it make not make a ton of sense but in multiple programming languages (certainly Java and Python) I've had to loop to get everything from a queue.  In Java it's something like (using the V2 api's):

```
// note that "done" needs to be set somewhere else to stop the loop
while (!done) {
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
                    .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                    .waitTimeSeconds(20)
                    .build();
    List<Message> messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).messages();

    for (Message nextMessage : messages) {
        // do something with the message

       DeleteMessageRequest deleteMessageRequest = DeleteMessageRequest
                        .builder()
                        .queueUrl(queueUrl)
                        .receiptHandle(nextMessage.receiptHandle())
                        .build();

       sqsClient.deleteMessage(deleteMessageRequest);
   }
}
```

From what I've read it is because there are ultimately many servers behind SQS and a single call doesn't hit all of them - it takes multiple calls.  This is not a busy loop as the `waitTimeSeconds` does block if there is nothing to do.

Try something like this to read SQS.  It's not quite as elegant but it does work.